# Setting node.js TLS ciphers vs observed behavior

Tags: tls, cipher-selection, node.js

I have a node.js server that I'm configuring for TLS 1.2. I set the following options in the config of my [https server](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html):

```
ciphers: 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL',
honorCipherOrder: true,
secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
```

I then ran [cipherscan](https://github.com/jvehent/cipherscan) on the port it created and got this result:

```
prio  ciphersuite                  protocols  pfs                 curves
1     ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256      TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
2     AES128-GCM-SHA256            TLSv1.2    None                None
3     ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA            TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
4     RC4-SHA                      TLSv1.2    None                None
5     ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
6     ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
7     ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
8     AES256-GCM-SHA384            TLSv1.2    None                None
9     AES256-SHA256                TLSv1.2    None                None
10    AES256-SHA                   TLSv1.2    None                None
11    CAMELLIA256-SHA              TLSv1.2    None                None
12    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
13    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA         TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
14    AES128-SHA256                TLSv1.2    None                None
15    AES128-SHA                   TLSv1.2    None                None
16    CAMELLIA128-SHA              TLSv1.2    None                None
17    ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA       TLSv1.2    ECDH,P-256,256bits  prime256v1
18    DES-CBC3-SHA                 TLSv1.2    None                None

Certificate: trusted, 2048 bit, sha256WithRSAEncryption signature
TLS ticket lifetime hint: 7200
OCSP stapling: not supported
Cipher ordering: server
Curves ordering: server
Curves fallback: False

Fallbacks required:
big-SSLv3 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.0 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.1 config not supported, connection failed
big-TLSv1.2 no fallback req, connected: TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
```

Any idea why 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384' is not my top priority cipher? It doesn't matter so much to me, but I would like to understand what I'm seeing better.

Comment: Have you tried asking e.g. Indutny on github?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/818

Comment: Ok, probably comes down to my not really understanding the format of that string. I'll try tweaking it based on what I'm seeing in that discussion.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my list and it is being obeyed. Seems as though ECDSA may not be supported, but that is not a problem. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ben, you may post an answer to your owm question if you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ECDSA?

No ECDSA cert installed or no ECDSA-scan support in the tool you used, maybe?

Check with another tool. Or by hand on the command line with the `openssl s_client` command.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. A combination of me not reading the screen carefully enough, not understanding the cipher string well enough, and not realizing the my cert is RSA.